# How to validate combined uniqueness of two fields in Laravel 5.6?

Tags: laravel, validation, laravel-5.6, laravel-validation

Here is my validation rules:-

```
$validationCondition    = array(
                            'fname'     => 'required|min:2',
                            'lname'     => 'required|min:2',
                            'email'     => 'required|email|unique:users,email',
                            'isd'       => 'required|unique:users,isd',
                            'mobile'    => 'required',
                            'password'  => 'required'
                        );
$validationMessages     = array(
                            'fname.required'    => 'Please provide first name',
                            'fname.min'         => 'First name should be atleast 3 characters long',

                            'lname.required'    => 'Please provide last name',
                            'lname.min'         => 'Last name should be atleast 3 characters long',

                            'email.required'    => 'Please provide email',
                            'email.email'       => 'Please provide a valid email id',
                            'email.unique'      => 'This email id has already been registered. Choose any other valid email id.',

                            'isd.required'      => 'The city name should be atleast 3 characters long',

                            'mobile.required'   => 'Please provide mobile number',

                            'password.required' => 'Please provide password'
                        );
```

In the users table, both the **isd** and **mobile** are to be checked to ensure whether the contact number is unique.

How can I check that? I know how to check uniqueness of a single field, but don't know how to check combined value as unique.

Comment: I don't think there's a way to do this. But you can use this package to achieve your end goal: https://github.com/felixkiss/uniquewith-validator.

You can also try taking a stab at setting up some custom validators. https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#custom-validation-rules

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```php
$validationCondition = array(
    ...
    'isd' => 'required',
    'mobile' => 'required|unique:users,mobile,NULL,id,isd,' . $request->isd,
    ...
);
```

The meaning of that `unique` rule for `mobile` will be: "value of `mobile` must be unique among all existing users that have `isd` of the same value that came in request".

`$request` here is the instance of incoming request that you are validating (obviously).

Comment: perfect! That was a charm. What does the NULL do?

Comment: `NULL,id` section is responsible for `ignore` arguments of `unique` rule. Those are just default values for those arguments since we are not using them, but need to get to `where` arguments of unique rule. If you specify your model id instead of `NULL` then `unique` rule will ignore row that has this id (useful when updating existing row, so that his current values aren't included in uniqueness check). You can read more about it [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/validation#rule-unique)

Answer (score 1):

You can use like below

```
'mobile'  => 'required|unique:users,mobile,NULL,id,mobile,isd'
```

Get more details [from doc](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#rule-unique)

Comment: your link is now dead, think this is the current replacement
https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#rule-unique